# Approach to duplicate content like language plugins - without duplicating the page

Tags: translation

I'm a little stuck while working on a site. I have already an existing site, and the client would like to have two copies of some of the pages - which content is presented is controlled by a query param. So I can't really duplicate the page, and within our infrastructure, I can't create a multisite. I want to implement a rudimentary functionality like language plugins (or find a minimalistic plugin that does it) - including being able to show the admin UI where the title, the description and all the ACF fields can be edited.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: this is the purpose of the canonical URL and the language header tags, googles own documention shows how this is meant to work in the HTML

Comment: canonical URLs and language header tags are FE. I would like to be able to edit the content in both "languages" (these are not really languages, in my case it's whether the page has a tag) in the admin area - if the page has 2 different tags, I would be able to edit two versions.

Comment: what do you mean by FE? I think there's been a misunderstanding, can you speak in concrete terms with real examples?